# Ruby on Rails: See if a record exists that matches query on multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing an app that allows a user to answer a survey once, when they answer it (the first time) I'm capturing the users ip address and user agent (in the Test_users model).

What I'm trying to do is if the user navigates to the survey again they are redirected to a page telling them that they can only complete it once.

In the test controller, I'm thinking this should be:

```
def new
        #Find the Test
        @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])

        if [[a record in test_users exists with the test id / ip address / user agent]]
             redirect_to already_completed_path
        end
end
```

I'm struggling with what this if statement, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you having test id,ip address and user agent in your `test_users` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `exists?` method if you don't need the object for something else:

```
if Test.exists?(:test_id => params[:test_id], :ip_address => request.remote_ip, :user_agent => request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
  redirect_to already_completed_path
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the where clause and put all your conditions in it:

```
@test = Test.where("test_id = ? or ip_address = ? or user_agent = ?",
                   test_id, ip_address, user_agent)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming you are storing `request.remote_ip` and `request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` values in your `tests` table:

```
if @test.where(ip: request.remote_ip, user_agent: request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']).exists?
  redirect_to already_completed_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should be doing like this

In your Test Controller

```
def new
        #Find the Test
        @test = Test.find(params[:id]) #it should be `:id` not `:test_id` because the model wont be having its own foreign key in its own record

        @test_user = TestUser.where("test_id = ? or ip_address = ? or user_agent = ?",
                   test_id, ip_address, user_agent)

        if @test_user.exists?
         redirect_to already_completed_path
        else
         redirect_to new_path
```